# PHP form, how to return error in same page rather then die() on new page?

Tags: php, forms, output

Have been trying to output errors on the same page of the form, am using a PHP form.

```
<?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty name 
        if(empty($_POST['full_name'])) 
        { 
            return("Please enter your full name."); 
        } 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { 
            // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
            // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
            // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
            // exercise for you to implement yourself. 
            //die("Please enter a username."); 
            return("PUFTA KOLLOK");
        } 


        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            die("Please enter a password."); 
        } 



        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see: 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php 
        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
            die("Invalid E-Mail Address"); 
        } 

        // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the 
        // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database. 
        // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when 
        // we execute the query. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users_pharm
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in 
        // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token 
        // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into 
        // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your 
        // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this. 
        // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from 
        // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in 
        // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue. 
        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This username is already in use"); 
        } 

        // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
        // to ensure that it is unique. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users_pharm 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            die("This email address is already registered"); 
        } 

        // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
        // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
        // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users_pharm ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                full_name,
                pharmacy    
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email,
                :full_name,
                :pharmacy

            ) 
        "; 

        // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
        // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
        // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
        // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read. 
        // For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
        // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
        // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original 
        // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
        // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
        // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password 
        // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
        // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not 
        // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store 
        // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk). 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':full_name' => $_POST['full_name'],
            ':pharmacy' => $_POST['pharmacy']   

        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        die("Redirecting to login.php"); 
    } 



?> 
<html>
<head>
<!--document's CSS styling -->
<link href="css/testcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<div id="header" style="text-align:left">
<body>
<h1>Pharmacists Registration</h1> 
<form action="register2.php" method="post"> <br />

    Full Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="full_name" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    Pharmacy :<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="pharmacy" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    E-Mail:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    <table>
        <tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" /> 
</form>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Back">
</form>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

Have researched and found about ajax, but am in no position to revamp the form from scratch.
Also have tried print(), return() error() but am all returning on new page the error apart from return which returns blank on new page.

This is the login page which is able to do what I require, that of display erro on same page. Have tried to get down to the bit in achieving this.. but All I'm noticing is that validation is in curly brackets and simply trigger a boolean. if false print error.. but I've tried the print() yet it's achieving ouutput on new page for the form but on same page for the login...here's the login page's code..

```
<?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    error_reporting(0);

    // This variable will be used to re-display the user's username to them in the 
    // login form if they fail to enter the correct password.  It is initialized here 
    // to an empty value, which will be shown if the user has not submitted the form. 
    $submitted_username = ''; 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        if($_POST['login_type']=="doctor_login") {

        // This query retreives the user's information from the database using 
        // their username. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                full_name
            FROM users 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // The parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query against the database 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not. 
        // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not. 
        // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true. 
        $login_ok = false; 

        // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username 
        // they entered is not registered. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 
            // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database, 
            // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password 
            // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database. 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

            if($check_password === $row['password']) 
            { 
                // If they do, then we flip this to true 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 

        // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
        // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
        if($login_ok) 
        { 
            // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by 
            // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is 
            // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values 
            // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these 
            // sensitive values first. 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 

            // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'. 
            // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether 
            // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve 
            // the user's details. 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

            // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
            header("Location: private.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: private.php"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Tell the user they failed 
            print("Login Failed."); 

            // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new 
            // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should 
            // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them 
            // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information: 
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        }
        }

        else if($_POST['login_type']=="pharmacist_login")
        {

            // This query retreives the user's information from the database using 
        // their username. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                id, 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                full_name
            FROM users_pharm 
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // The parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query against the database 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage() ); 
        } 

        // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not. 
        // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not. 
        // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true. 
        $login_ok = false; 

        // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username 
        // they entered is not registered. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 
            // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database, 
            // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password 
            // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database. 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

            if($check_password === $row['password']) 
            { 
                // If they do, then we flip this to true 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 

        // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
        // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
        if($login_ok) 
        { 
            // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by 
            // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is 
            // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values 
            // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these 
            // sensitive values first. 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 

            // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'. 
            // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether 
            // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve 
            // the user's details. 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

            // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
            header("Location: private2.php"); 
            die("Redirecting to: private2.php"); 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Tell the user they failed 
            print("Login Failed."); 

            // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new 
            // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should 
            // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them 
            // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information: 
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        }

        }
    } 

?> 

<html>

<head>
<!--document's CSS styling -->
<link href="css/testcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="header" style="text-align:left">
<br />
<h1>Login</h1> 
<form action="login.php" method="post"> 
    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 
    <!--<form>-->
        <input type="radio" name="login_type" value="pharmacist_login" id="pharmacist_login"/> Pharmacist Login
        <br /><input type="radio" name="login_type" value="doctor_login" id="doctor_login"/> G.P Login<br />
    <!--</form>-->
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" /> 

    <form action="forgotpassword.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Forgot Password" /> 
    </form>


</form> 

<br />
<a href="register.php">General Practitioner's Registration</a>
<br />
<a href="register2.php">Pharmacist's Registration</a>
<br />
<a href="forgot_password.php">Forgot Password</a>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I would've suggested using ajax, too bad you don't want to give it a try, well, have you considered JavaScript ?

Comment: It's not useful to post Pastebins, please put your code in your question (especially if you let the Pastebin expire within 24 hours). Use the code formatting button (that reads `{}`) to indent your code with 4 spaces.

Comment: whenever I use that feature and pastes the code, it wouldn't let me submit my post, saying error in indentation as I understood that there must be four indentations for code. Yet although I indent my code before posting, when I paste it some of it still becomes unindented..therefore the error stops me from submitting

Comment: Then indent your code with 4 spaces *after* you paste it, like I did with the code formatting button. And use @-replies to call someone else then the OP.

Comment: is this question still open? if it's not then please mark an answer. if it is then I'll take a shot at it

Answer (score 1):

when you using from $_POST and $_GET(or other PHP Coding ) page send to server and current  page waiting from result page from server.
if your means that show error on same page of form clause you can do this(an Editing of your Code ) :

```
<?php 

    // First we execute our common code to connection to the database and start the session 
    require("common.php"); 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the registration form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the registration code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    $ErrorTest="";
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty name 
        if(empty($_POST['full_name'])) 
        { 
            $ErrorTest="Please enter your full name.";
        } 

        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty username 
        if(empty($_POST['username'])) 
        { 
            // Note that die() is generally a terrible way of handling user errors 
            // like this.  It is much better to display the error with the form 
            // and allow the user to correct their mistake.  However, that is an 
            // exercise for you to implement yourself. 
            //die("Please enter a username."); 
            $ErrorTest .="PUFTA KOLLOK";
        } 


        // Ensure that the user has entered a non-empty password 
        if(empty($_POST['password'])) 
        { 
            $ErrorTest.="Please enter a password."; 
        } 



        // Make sure the user entered a valid E-Mail address 
        // filter_var is a useful PHP function for validating form input, see: 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php 
        // http://us.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php 
        if ($ErrorTest=="")  // add this line where you want avoid run

        if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
        { 
           $ErrorTest="Invalid E-Mail Address"=; 




        // We will use this SQL query to see whether the username entered by the 
        // user is already in use.  A SELECT query is used to retrieve data from the database. 
        // :username is a special token, we will substitute a real value in its place when 
        // we execute the query. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users_pharm
            WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // This contains the definitions for any special tokens that we place in 
        // our SQL query.  In this case, we are defining a value for the token 
        // :username.  It is possible to insert $_POST['username'] directly into 
        // your $query string; however doing so is very insecure and opens your 
        // code up to SQL injection exploits.  Using tokens prevents this. 
        // For more information on SQL injections, see Wikipedia: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Injection 
        if ($ErrorTest=="")

        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 


        try 
        { 
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            $ErrorTest="Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // The fetch() method returns an array representing the "next" row from 
        // the selected results, or false if there are no more rows to fetch. 


        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        // If a row was returned, then we know a matching username was found in 
        // the database already and we should not allow the user to continue. 


        if($row) 
        { 
            $ErrorTest="This username is already in use"; 
        } 

        // Now we perform the same type of check for the email address, in order 
        // to ensure that it is unique. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                1 
            FROM users_pharm 
            WHERE 
                email = :email 
        "; 

        $query_params = array( 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            $ErrorTest="Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage(); 
        } 

        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

        if($row) 
        { 
            $ErrorTest="This email address is already registered"; 
        } 

        // An INSERT query is used to add new rows to a database table. 
        // Again, we are using special tokens (technically called parameters) to 
        // protect against SQL injection attacks. 
        $query = " 
            INSERT INTO users_pharm ( 
                username, 
                password, 
                salt, 
                email,
                full_name,
                pharmacy    
            ) VALUES ( 
                :username, 
                :password, 
                :salt, 
                :email,
                :full_name,
                :pharmacy

            ) 
        "; 

        // A salt is randomly generated here to protect again brute force attacks 
        // and rainbow table attacks.  The following statement generates a hex 
        // representation of an 8 byte salt.  Representing this in hex provides 
        // no additional security, but makes it easier for humans to read. 
        // For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brute-force_attack 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table 
        $salt = dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)) . dechex(mt_rand(0, 2147483647)); 

        // This hashes the password with the salt so that it can be stored securely 
        // in your database.  The output of this next statement is a 64 byte hex 
        // string representing the 32 byte sha256 hash of the password.  The original 
        // password cannot be recovered from the hash.  For more information: 
        // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function 
        $password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $salt); 

        // Next we hash the hash value 65536 more times.  The purpose of this is to 
        // protect against brute force attacks.  Now an attacker must compute the hash 65537 
        // times for each guess they make against a password, whereas if the password 
        // were hashed only once the attacker would have been able to make 65537 different  
        // guesses in the same amount of time instead of only one. 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
        { 
            $password = hash('sha256', $password . $salt); 
        } 

        // Here we prepare our tokens for insertion into the SQL query.  We do not 
        // store the original password; only the hashed version of it.  We do store 
        // the salt (in its plaintext form; this is not a security risk). 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'], 
            ':password' => $password, 
            ':salt' => $salt, 
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':full_name' => $_POST['full_name'],
            ':pharmacy' => $_POST['pharmacy']   

        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query to create the user 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            $ErrorTest="Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage(); 
        } 

        // This redirects the user back to the login page after they register 
        header("Location: login.php"); 

        // Calling die or exit after performing a redirect using the header function 
        // is critical.  The rest of your PHP script will continue to execute and 
        // will be sent to the user if you do not die or exit. 
        $ErrorTest="Redirecting to login.php"; 
    } 



?> 
<html>
<head>
<!--document's CSS styling -->
<link href="css/testcss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<div id="header" style="text-align:left">
<body>
<h1>Pharmacists Registration</h1> 
<?php>
if ($ErrorTest!="")
  echo "<br />Error:".$ErrorTest."<br />";
if (empty($_POST) || $ErrorTest!="" ) 
{
<?>
<form action="register2.php" method="post"> <br />

    Full Name:<br />
    <input type="text" name="full_name" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    Username:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="username" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    Pharmacy :<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="pharmacy" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    E-Mail:<br /> 
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    Password:<br /> 
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
    <br /><br /> 

    <table>
        <tr>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" /> 
</form>
<?php>
}
<?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Back">
</form>
</body>
</div>

</html>
```

you can using if condition from where you want in code

```
   if ($ErrorTest=="")
      do next step
```

Comment: Thanks man your answer got the closest to where I intend to go. It's outputting on same page. Yet It always mention email error which is last overwritten string during validation of name username and email.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write upper part of code in register2.php and use session and header to return in same page as follows.

```
 session_start();
 if(!empty($_POST))
 {
    if(empty($_POST['full_name']))
    {
        $_SESSION['error'] = "Please enter your full name.";
        header("Location: pagename.php");
    } else {
        $_SESSION["full_name"] = $_POST["full_name"];
    }
    if(empty($_POST['password']))
    {
        $_SESSION["error"] = "Please enter a password.";
        header("Location:pagename.php");
    } 
}
```

and in pagename.php, you can retrieve the data that is entered by user in previous page as follows:

```
session_start();
$full_name = $_SESSION["full_name"]; 
$error = $_SESSION["error"];
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Moreover, if you want to do javascript validation, then there is a nice jquery plugin available. See documentation and demo at http://demos.usejquery.com/ketchup-plugin/

Comment: If I'm understanding well, you're code if empty stored the error string in a variable error within the session and redirects to indicated page. Else it stores the input value to the sessions matching variable. But error output.. I cannot understand where it takes place. Did you mean to output the error string by echoing $_SESSION['error']?